# Android Studio/Eclipse - restrict screen resolution to minimum 720x1280

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, screen, resolution

I am coding a Cordova Application and my CSS is Optimized for screen resolution higher than 720x1280. I want to ban the phones which are using 400x800 / 480x800.

```
android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="720"
```

Is putting the above line in my manifest the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Google Play [does not use this attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#requiresSmallest), so you should use supports-screens attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="false" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

[More info here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range)